# Allow sorting of answers within the iOS app and/or jumping to latest active item

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Currently there doesn't seem to be a way to sort a question's answers in the iOS app, making it difficult to find the post which was responsible for the last activity on the question.

Please make it possible to sort the answers by at least votes or activity, and possibly provide a shortcut to the most recently active item so I don't have to do any investigative work to determine which it is.

Comment: You can't even sort by newest which on sandbox posts (like the PPCG meta one), very frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

This is surprisingly annoying, especially on Meta. It occurred to me this is one of only three features I routinely leave the app for.

It does seem easy enough to implement though. Two possibilities:

1. *(easier to find)* In the top bar, show an icon where the inbox icon isn't<sup>1</sup>. The icon should only be visible when on the answers tab.

   > [image]
2. *(more consistent)* Add a "negative" row you can pull down to reveal. Without the search bar, I don't really know what should go on the left. I added an overly wordy sort description to fill in the space:

   > [image]

<sup>1</sup> Hmm. *Why* isn't the inbox there? I've always just taken it for granted that it shouldn't be, but now I can't think of a reason. *I want it!*

Comment: I'd rather do it like your second idea, since that's what we're doing for question lists too. The inbox isn't in that view since it made the top bar really cluttered.

Comment: Yeah, I like the second one more too. Don't know I agree about the clutter though. But I'll make a post about that and let the masses vote...

Comment: [done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231368/show-inbox-in-question-answer-view)