# Show iOS app inbox in question/answer view

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, ios-app

I would like this:

> [image]

But [Kasra says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220389/allow-sorting-of-answers-within-the-ios-app-and-or-jumping-to-latest-active-item#comment760272_231359)

> The inbox isn't in that view since it made the top bar really cluttered.

I say bring it on!

Allow me to give a simple anecdote of why this is worth sacrificing Kasra's design sensibilities:

1. I read a post
2. I left a comment
3. I got a reply
4. I didn't know because I was still reading the post
5. The end

For some reason I'd always assumed it was a technical limitation. It seems it's just a choice, so I bring it to the house floor for a vote. Do you want the inbox in the view that already has the **question** and **answers** buttons up there? Or is it really too cluttered?