# Add an answer to the question with many existing answers already

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Tried to add an answer to [formatting sandbox post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/339911) via ios-app, but tired to reach "add an answer" button by scrolling down.

Is it possible to add an answer without scrolling over all existing answers via ios-app?

On the web I need to scroll only answers on the first page to reach desired button.

Comment: Yes please! It's rare for questions to get enough answers for this to be an issue but it is *very* frustrating when it does happen.

Comment: To help with scrolling past long answers you can use the up/down arrows top right in the app.

Comment: @Notts90 more easiest way in this case is to open question in the web browser. But this is non-app way already.

Comment: @Notts90 another way to achieve this is to implement [requested feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220389/339911).